# Php - run another page and go

Tags: php, asynchronous

i've a question, in a php script I've to do some things, and I need to be really fust, but in the script I've to do some database controlls, too, so, I would know if it's possible run an external php page, that do something, but without wait for its results.
Thanks
(P.S.: sorry for my english)

Comment: you can call that php script (page) through curl...

Comment: PHP isn't multi-threaded. As far as I'm aware there is no way to do this.

Comment: You can make ajax async calls to that page.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to look at using Javascript and Ajax. This allows you to run a php script from within a page asynchronously.

If you use a javascript library, such as [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) then you can use something similar to this:

```
$.get('my_script.php', function(response) {
    // This code is ran when the page has been loaded
    // `response` is the content you get back from script
});
```

For more information have a look at the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) on the `$.get` function.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use Ajax for this. Using Ajax you can run php code in the background, however if user navigates to another page, the execution of that php code will be terminated. The simplest way to get started with Ajax is to use a library like jQuery. See http://www.devirtuoso.com/2009/07/beginners-guide-to-using-ajax-with-jquery/

Hope this helps

--EDIT--
This how you can achieve calling exec(php script.php) using Ajax and PHP

home.php (here you are using Ajax to run exec.php)

```
<!--include the jQuery library -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
function runInBackground(){
   $.get('exec.php', function(data) {
  });
}
</script>
```

exec.php

```
<?php
 exec(php script.php);
?>
```

Comment: i'm intrested if i can use smth like `exec('php script.php')` for that purpose?

Comment: I have never had to exec before, but I dont think it can run in the background when call on it own. however, you can have that code in a separate php script and call it using Ajax. Will edit my answer soon to demonstrate what I mean

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ajax to do that, it let another script run in background.